# Yii2. Class does not exist

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Шаблон приложения advanced.

У меня есть модуль в common `common\modules\setting\Module`

Необходим компонент. Внутри модуля делаю папку "components": `common\modules\setting\components`
В эту папку ложу файл с именем SettingComponent.php
Содержимое файла:

```
namespace common\modules\setting\components;

use yii\base\Component;

class SettingComponent extends Component
{
    // some code...
}
```

В `common\config\main.php` я подключаю компонент следующим образом:

```
[
    'components' => [
        'setting' => [
            'class' => 'common\modules\setting\components\SettingComponent',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
ReflectionException
Class common\modules\setting\components\SettingComponent does not exist
```

Вот срин иерархии на всякий случай:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Может потому, что надо в конфиге не в `components` писать, а в `modules` ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#using-modules  ......... https://youtu.be/GtHB58-JA38

Comment: Зачем? Модуль я подключаю отельно так: `'setting' => [ 'class' => common\modules\setting\Module::className() ]` Мне надо чтобы я мог в любом месте приложения обращаться к этому компоненту так: `\Yii::$app->setting`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В файлах-то вы прописали все верно, а вот директорию как обозвали? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вроде 10 раз уже проверял, перечитывал по буквам и не заметил... Ужас. 4 часа потрачено :((( Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Бывает) В таком случае полезнее отдохнуть немного и посмотреть свежим взглядом, чтобы не убивать 4 часа.